# MySql query slow when using multiple indexes

Tags: mysql

I have query

```
select * from table where field='sometext' and state=0

field varchar(50), index
state int(1), index (may be 0|1)
```

query takes about 2 seconds (~2 000 000 records in table) 
when  `select * from table where field='sometext'` takes 0.0002 about seconds
How can i optimize table ? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the full table definition and an execution plan for both queries?

Comment: you need to have a multiple column index `table(field, state)`  to optimize the search `field='sometext' and state=0`.. like described here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: If you have many columns in your table, then `SELECT *` might cause MySQL to not use _any_ index, if that index would not cover all the columns being selected.

Comment: "If you have many columns in your table, then SELECT * might cause MySQL to not use any index" never heard of that one.. I believe the MySQL optimizer is record based only not column based also unless there is a change made in MySQL 8.0 @TimBiegeleisen can you provide a source/documentation?

Comment: @RaymondNijland If you don't understand how indices work in SQL, then I would recommend refreshing your knowledge, or maybe taking a course somewhere.  When the index reaches the leaf nodes, if the columns being selected aren't covered there, then MySQL would have do another lookup into the clustered index to find the values there.  This can be costly, and therefore could result in the optimizer just choosing to completely ignore the index and do a full scan.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i now see what you mean.. Trust me i know how indexes work so i don't need to restudy that thank you for suggesting.. Besides the MySQL optimizer has pretty large code with alot of variables in here sometimes not everything is explained in MySQL docs how the optimizer works under the hood that's why i look into the source code...i can't remember/recall annything in the optimizers source code which looks at the tables columns number and choosing a different query plan/execution based on that..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I appreciate your constructive criticism.  Not every query can be optimized.  Maybe this one can be, but a common misconception I see on SO is that many folks think that just by adding an index to a column, the query is guaranteed to run fast.  This sometimes is not the case.

Comment: " I see on SO is that many folks think that just by adding an index to a column, the query is guaranteed to run fast. This sometimes is not the case" @TimBiegeleisen yes iam aware of that it's still the optimizers choose if the index will be used or not depending of this selectivity.. I also should have used you "can try" in the comment where i suggested the multiple column index.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple-Column indexes are solution.
thanks [Raymond Nijland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548147/raymond-nijland)